# How to override fn_get_filters_products_count() in my addon

Tags: php, cs-cart

I added new featuretype such as z,w.
Now I need to display the this feature type filter also. So I need to override the `fn_get_filters_products_count()` in my addon.

In `fn_get_filters_products_count()` only support `'S', 'M', 'E'` feature type . I need to support `'S','M','E','Z','W'` .

I have `fn_get_filters_products_count_post()` in myaddon.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Kingsley,

In case you want to change the behavior of a function you should extend it using hook (See docs what is hooks here: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.0.x/addons/hooking/php_hooks.html).

So in your case you can if you want to do a post processing of fn_get_filters_products_count function result, you can use the "get_product_features_post" hook.

In order to use it you should do the following:

1. Add a new hook declaration in you add-on init.php file. It should look like this:
2. Add a new function in your add-on func.php file. E.g. if add-on ID is "my_changes" than you should define new function:

   fn_my_changes_get_product_features_post($data, $params, $has_ungroupped) {
        //Your code here

   }

But to be ownest I'm not sure that you need a post processing of result. Probably you need the "get_product_features" hook to change SQL parameters and thus extend the query.